# apply a filter on images, to make them appear like they are taken from further away

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, blur

I want to apply a filter on images, to make them appear like they are taken from further away, as they really are.

**For reference:**

Left image below is from ~1m away from the plant.

Right image is from 10m away.

[image]

Which filters or combination of filters should I use to get the right image from the left one. I suppose I can use some sort of blurring and pixelation.
I wanted to ask here, so see if there is kind of a standard way to do this in image processing that gives realistic results.

I need to implement this in python 3 and I know how to implement a blur with opencv.

Comment: This might be an opinionated question since the approach you described works fine and there isn't really any 1 true answer

Comment: To me the image on the right looks nearer than the left image

Comment: The main difference between pictures taken at different distances is the perspective distortion. You cannot fake that with filters, you can only simulate it if you have a depth map of the scene as well. This is an example of the distortions you get at short distances (left) compared to long distances (right): https://i1.wp.com/animoto.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Focal-Length-Collage.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do a cubic downsample, then a nearest neighbor upsample, with a little blur for polish:

```
img = cv2.imread(impath,-1)
w,h = img.shape[:2]
down = cv2.resize(img,(int(w/3),int(h/3)),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
up = cv2.resize(down,(w,h),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
up = cv2.GaussianBlur(up,(5,5),2.4,2.4)
cv2.imshow('',up)
cv2.imshow('in',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]